# How do I iterate over one collection and use each value to update a document array in another collection?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have edited this question again.
This seems to work, but **should I be using promises or async / await?**
When I use this code inside a larger piece of code there seem to be some async issues. I'd value advice.

I'm working with express.js and mongoose and a MongoDB database.

I have 2 collections - a **customer** collection and a **product** collection.

As well as some product details (name, code, stock and price) the product collection has an '**order**' array that holds details (customer ID, quantity ordered and order date) of any current orders on that product.

I am trying to create an update that will look at a specific product, and create/push new orders for that product for any customers who do **not** have any current orders for that product.

I have managed to do this, by iterating over the customer collection, and for each customer, checking if there is an order in the product collection for the particular product code I want. If there is NOT an existing order for that customer, I push a new order onto the order array; if there IS an existing order, I do nothing - then move on and check the next customer etc.

Although my code works, I am a relative newcomer to MongoDB, and it seems to me there is probably a more elegant way to achieve this. So I welcome suggestions and advice.

Here is the Customer collection schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create schema
const CustomerSchema = new Schema({
 name:{
  type: String
 },
 customerCode:{
  type: String
 },
 address:{
  type: String
 },  
 phone: {
  type: String
 }
});

mongoose.model('customers', CustomerSchema);
```

and here is the Product collection schema that references the customer collection:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create schema
const ProductSchema = new Schema({
  name:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  productCode:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  stock:{
    type: Number
  },  
  price: {
    type: Number
  },
  order:{
    [
      {
        customer:{
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'customers'
        },
        quantity:{
          type: Number
        },
        orderDate:{
          type: Date,
          default: Date.now
        }
      }
    ]
  }
});

mongoose.model('products', ProductSchema);
```

And here's a simple example of the specific product document I want to update. You can see that 2 customers have current orders for this product. My update code needs to add orders with quantity = 1 for all other customers.

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5d4fd81f7c08ae0efa96b762"),
"name" : "Paper 180gsm white bond",
"productCode" : "P180120",
"stock" : 100,
"price" : 14.99,
"order" : [
    {
        "customer" : ObjectId("5d4fd6f37c08ae0efa96b75c"),
        "quantity" : 2,
        "orderDate" : ISODate("2019-08-12T23:56:45.238Z")
    },
    {
        "customer" : ObjectId("5d4fd6f37c08ae0efa96b75e"),
        "quantity" : 2,
        "orderDate" : ISODate("2019-08-12T23:56:45.238Z")
    }
]
```

Here is my code. It works, but I think it is probably unecessarily complicated and not at all elegant.

```
// Get a cursor with all customers
Customer.find({})
.then (theseCustomers => {

    // Iterate over the customers using forEach
    theseCustomers.forEach((thisCustomer) => {

    // Look in the Product collection for a document
    // that has the specific product code AND an order for this customer
    Product.findOne({productCode: "P180120", "order.customer": thisCustomer._id})
    .then (thisProduct => {

      if(thisProduct === null) {
        // No order exists for this customer, so add it and save
        Product.findOne({productCode: "P180120"})
        .then(record => {
          record.order.push({customer: thisCustomer._id, quantity: 1});
          record.save()
          .then(() => {
            console.log("New order added");
          })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log("Error saving new order");
        });
      });

    } else {
      // An order already exists for this customer, so do nothing
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "adding a free promotional order for everyone. But do take a look at mongodb `$lookup`. It's similar to a left outer join. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: Thanks Praveen. I have edited and removed the confusing "free promotional order" reference above. Although mongodb $lookup is interesting I cannot see how it will help me here.